# PyMySQL and deadlock

Tags: python, mysql, deadlock, pymysql, database-deadlocks

For some reason I'm getting randomly an error message

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
```

on a simple update query which looks like

```
updateQuery = "UPDATE %s SET valid = 1 WHERE uid = %s"
updateValues = (table, uid)
cursor.execute(updateQuery, updateValues)
db.commit()
```

Any thoughts on that? MySQL bug rather than code?

Comment: The deadlocks caused when 2 or more parallel transactions tried to get lock on same DB record. So it is not DB bug, you should re-design you code to prevent deadlocks. Using `SELECT * FROM %t WHERE name = '%u' FOR UPDATE;` may be helpful

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I know what is a deadlock but how it can happen when a script is a single thread and single process not even async for such of simple update query. It will be only one transaction unless another was too slow to finish before the same update will kick in.

Comment: Is `uid` have an index? Index will improve the performance. May be exists triggers on table update that caused to dead locks. Look next article for log dead locks: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87350/view-last-several-innodb-deadlocks

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Yes, `uid` has an index. As I have stated in the OP it is very random case but I'm trying to avoid it any possible way - can be code can be MySQL upgrade if needed.

Comment: Use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` to view more detailed information on the table(s) involved in the deadlock.